# JavaScript variable from inputfield value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to find a way that would allow me to set and update a javascript variable using an input field value.

Basically I am trying to create a simple web based navigation system using Google Map.

The normal variable looks like this:

```
var start =  [51.6111056367416, 0.08299685083337408];
```

the code above works fine. and it will show the correct location on the Google Map. However, I am trying to set and update variable value dynamically (maybe update it every few seconds).

so I am using AJAX to get the value from MYSQL database like so:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    function load() {
        $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "location.php",
            dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
            success: function (response) {
                $("#map-directions").html(response);

                var input = document.getElementById("map-directions").innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("map-txt").value = document.getElementById("map-directions").innerHTML;


                setTimeout(load, 8000);



            }

        });
    }

    load();
});
</script>
```

**and the HTML is this:**

```
<div id="map-directions"></div>
<input type="text" id="map-txt"  value="" />
```

so the code above will run every 8 seconds and will get the new data from MYSQL database and will put the new data in `map-directions` Div and will copy the same data into `map-txt` inputfield.

This also works fine.

Now, the issue that I have is that when i change the

```
var start =  [51.6111056367416, 0.08299685083337408];
```

TO

```
var start = document.getElementById("map-txt").value;
```

I get a strange location on the map which is an incorrect location!

Even though, the value of inputfield is exactly same as `[51.6111056367416, 0.08299685083337408];`

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: `document.getElementById("map-txt").value` gives you a string not array where as `[51.6111056367416, 0.08299685083337408]` is an Array

Comment: @codehx, but the value of map-txt input field is exactly 51.6111056367416, 0.08299685083337408!

Comment: it could be same but different data type. If you think the are actually same try this. `document.getElementById("map-txt").value[0]` which will give you the fist character than the first array element. Am posting it as answer with more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The **trick** is with this line ( issue of datatype):

```
document.getElementById("map-txt").value = document.getElementById("map-directions").innerHTML;
```

you are getting the data and putting in a text box which is being saved as string variable.

In short.

```
var start =  [51.6111056367416, 0.08299685083337408]; //data type array
```

`start[0]` will give you `51.6111056367416`

where as

```
document.getElementById("map-txt").value = [51.6111056367416, 0.08299685083337408]

var start = document.getElementById("map-txt").value; //data type string
```

`start[0]` will give you `5` instead of `51.6111056367416`.

Hope it will help,

Comment: the thing is the value of map-txt is an AJAX response so it cannot be document.getElementById("map-txt").value = [51.6111056367416, 0.08299685083337408].

Comment: I am just giving you an example , whatever you put on ` document.getElementById("map-txt").value` is string. you cant assign it to array variable.

Comment: This line is not correct:`var start = document.getElementById("map-txt").value;`

Comment: If you want to get same effect you have to say, `var start = document.getElementById("map-txt").value.split(",");` and then `parseInt` each value if necessary

Comment: why would I get rid of the (,) ? without it I get the both numbers attached to eachother and i get a long number like this: 51.61110563674160.08299685083337408

Comment: I did not say get rid of it! Split function will split the string into array (` ["51.6111056367416", "0.08299685083337408"]`)then all you have to do is parse each string to number.

Comment: then please check var start = document.getElementById("map-txt").value.split(","); IF you can because that is exactly what it does! it gets rid of the (,) from between the numbers and it attaches two numbers together and creates a new LONG number.

Comment: and this still doesn't answer my question! but never mind.... I'll sort it out...

Comment: But does the split function work as you stated it above?

Answer (score -2):

Prepare an array for an input to ajax call with values from trim function as below:

```
var test=document.getElementById("map-txt").value.trim(',');
```

Comment: won't this just get rid of the (,) ?

Answer (score -2):

All I had to do was this:

```
var data = document.getElementById("map-txt").value;

var start = eval("[" + data + "]");
```

Comment: It is okay we all made silly mistakes but accepting your mistakes and accepting correct answer is the discipline of _stackoverflow_

Comment: @codehx, and your answer is exactly a prime example of what I said before( "going round and round the circle instead of actually saying this is how its done" ). the mistake that so many STO-ers make when they try to answer a question is that they "assume" and they don't give a correct answer. see, you could have ended your answer with 2 lines of code if you knew the answer. but instead you went round the circle about 20 times and still haven't given the correct answer.

Comment: you just posted a solution you found it googling may be you dont know the exact reason of your mistake. what was your mistake?

Comment: At least use `JSON.parse("[" + data + "]")` or something instead…

Comment: `eval` evaluates arbitrary JavaScript. If `map-txt` is a textbox, for example, putting in `hello, world` will throw, and `]; while (true); [` will cause your page to hang.